# How to display all the month names in an Oracle report?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

What is the SQL query to display all the months name in the year
when the user inputs the date range of values ? The results should display all the month name in header whether if the month does not contain any values.

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_CODE, ITS.ITEMS_NAME, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY')MON, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')MM, SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
FROM CUSTOMERS CU, ITEMS ITS, TRANS_MASTER TM, TRANS_DETAIL TD
WHERE CU.CUST_CODE=TM.CUST_CODE
AND ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
AND TM.INVOICE_NO = TD.INVOICE_NO
GROUP BY CU.CUST_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_NAME,TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY MM ASC
```

Comment: how to display the month as JAN,FEB.... from the given range using the above query

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

`to_char(TM.JOB_DATE, 'MON' )` to get Month like 'JAN','FEB'..

Comment: but in the above query i have added this char... , but what exactly i need is when an user inputs an particular date of an month the data should display as well all other months should also display with the NULL values if the month doesnt contain any data or values. but all the 12 month should be displayed !

Comment: you can try this  NVL(to_char(TM.JOB_DATE, 'MON' ), 'Not Applicable')